# ClassCastException with ServiceTestRule's bindService method

Tags: android, junit, kotlin

I have written a function to get bound services using the ServiceTestRule, which is as follows:

```
class Parent {
    companion object {
        fun <T : AbstractUIService> getBoundService(clazz: Class<T>): T {
            var binder: IBinder? = null
            while (binder == null) {
                binder = serviceTestRule.bindService(
                    Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().applicationContext, clazz))
            }
            return (binder as LocalBinder<T>).service
        }
    }
}
```

This class is inherited by the classes which have the test cases. I get the 'bound service' using this function in the child class' companion object's @BeforeClass function.

```
class ChildATests: Parent() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var serviceA: ServiceA

        @BeforeClass @JvmStatic
        fun setUp() {
            serviceA = getBoundService(ServiceA::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine if I have to run just one Child*Tests class. But when I run the whole suite, the first class runs fine but the rest of the classes fail with the following error:

*java.lang.ClassCastException: ServiceB cannot be cast to ServiceA*

Please note that I can only get one bound service within a Child*Tests class. If I try to get another bound service in the same class it fails with the same error.

If more details are needed to clarify the situation, then please let me know.

Comment: I have two different class ...
Test runs on class A sucessfully
but when test runs on class B it say class csat except ... binder of Class A cannot be cast to B. I dont know why.... both classes are using ServiceTestRule

Comment: Regarding your last statement, we can get only one bindService in child test class..so we should get the service at class level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is using the ServiceConnection adapter with the ServiceTestRule's bindService method. So my getBoundService function now looks like this:

```
fun <T : AbstractUIService> getBoundService(clazz: Class<T>): T {
    val serviceConnectionAdapter = doOperationWithLatch {
        val adapter = ServiceConnectionAdapter(it)
        serviceTestRule.bindService(
                Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().applicationContext, clazz),
                adapter,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
        )
        adapter
    } as ServiceConnectionAdapter

    return (serviceConnectionAdapter.service as LocalBinder<T>).service
}
```

where `it` is a CountDownLatch.

Comment: Hi @NSaran
I am facing similar issue.. Using ServiceTestRule where bindService() returns mBinder for one test case and for the whole suit it is returning ... bindService() cannot be null. Error

Comment: My observations are when using Service test rule...you can get binder only once..  ( case when you are depending upon the internal service connection) for next test case. bindServuce always returns null... ( as on ServiceConnected method doesn't get called here)

Comment: The bindService caches the service it found during the first invocation. So on the second invocation it returns the cached value and you see the Exception. The correct way to use this android API is to register a listener for the result of the Intent.